# Need to output all prime numbers

Tags: java

for the example 60 the answer should be 2 2 3 5 but it only comes up with 2 3 5.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeFactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter a positive number: ");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        int number = scanner.nextInt();

        int count;

        for (int i = 2; i<=(number); i++) {
            count = 0;

            while (number % i == 0) {
                number /= i;
                count++;
                    }

            if (count == 0) {
                    continue;
            }
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: completely different code

Comment: i just used his code quickly and his displays the fact that 2 is used twice in a way of 2**2 but i want it to come up 2 (with a space here) 2

Comment: is there any way i can just make it display all primes of the number which in the case of 60 would be 2 2 3 5

Comment: @user2230190 So, since you know that `count` has the value of the number of times you want 2 printed, how can you exploit that? A `for` loop maybe?

Comment: would you be able to write that out as a code? im new and dont exactly know all types of code yet

Comment: Yes I could, but then you would not learn as much as you will by figuring out on your own. I have given a hint about a for loop, so read about for loops in your java programming book and I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once it finds that 60 is divisible by 2, it keeps dividing it by 2 (in this case twice).

place the final bracket of the while statement AFTER the System.out.print and it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter a positive number: ");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        int number = scanner.nextInt();

        int count;

        for (int i = 2; i<=(number); i++) {
            count = 0;

            while (number % i == 0) {
                number /= i;
                count++;


            if (count == 0) {
                    continue;
            }
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Héctor van den Boorn you are the man

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a different way to do it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive number: ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

            int number = scanner.nextInt();

            int divisor = 2;
            while(number != 1) {
            if(number % divisor == 0) {
                System.out.println(divisor + " ");
                number /= divisor;
            }
            else {
                divisor++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```